# SXA 1.6 Creative Exchange Import Export options grayed out

Tags: sxa

I recently updated from SXA 1.4 to 1.6 and now the Import and Export buttons are grayed out. Any ideas on how to fix this?

We are on Sitecore 8.2 update 6.

[image]

Comment: What is your context item? Are you on some page? Buttons are disabled if you are for example on a partial design. Another reason could be that module was not enabled when you've created a site.

Comment: Please provide some more details so that people can understand the exact question/problem you are facing. Since it is your first question on the community, I would encourage you to please refer this URL:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Additionally was it working fine with SXA 1.4?

Comment: Yes, Creative Exchange Exports and Imports were working correctly before the update (Sitecore 8.2u4 to 8.2u6 and SXA 1.4 to 1.6). After the update, the buttons are grayed out for all pages under the content tree. The buttons are unusable inside the content editor and inside the experience editor. I have the Showcase tenant installed and the same problem exists with it too.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem go the Tenant > Site > Configuration > Features add the feature Creative Exchange Site Setup (Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Creative Exchange Site Setup ).

[image]