# SXA 1.6 Creative Exchange Import error after upgrade

Tags: sxa, configuration

I recently upgraded from 8.2u4 to 8.2u6 and SXA 1.4 to SXA 1.6 and ran into some issues found here. [SXA 1.6 Creative Exchange Import Export options grayed out](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/sxa-1-6-creative-exchange-import-export-options-grayed-out?noredirect=1#comment14563_9494). After resolving this issue, I thought all was good. Until I needed to import and received the following error.

> "No locator provider is configured at
>   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.IoC.ServiceLocator.get_Current()..."

Screenshot is attached for the reference.

[image]

The issue has been resolved but I thought I would post the answer in case someone else runs into the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a patch that is under \App_Config\Include\zzz\Sitecore.Support.9318.config that is causing the issue. Once the patch is removed the Import works correctly. There is also an assembly file in the bin folder that needs to be removed.

```
<assembly name="Sitecore.Support.9318.dll">
    <fileVersion>1.4.0.0</fileVersion>
    <productVersion>1.4.0.0-8.2.4</productVersion>
    <lastWriteTime>11/07/2017 09:23:00</lastWriteTime>
    <md5>67FC4466CE890D60344842D437698089</md5>
  </assembly>
```

[image]

Apparently, the patch has been incorporated into 1.6 and is no longer needed.

I hope this helps.